# Python - unable to open modules as a command/function

Tags: python, global

I defined several functions that are made with the purpose of taking the user from one module to another, my issue is that these functions are unable to work.

The error that I receive when trying to use the function appears as follows:

```
NameError: global name 'Hospital' is not defined
```

For reference, my function appears as follows:

```
def hospital_travel():
    print("Hospital is launching now.")

Hospital.py.hospital_travel()
```

I am unsure what is causing the issue, any feedback would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Where is `Hospital` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following commands in python terminal:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend('Path of your module')
import module_name
module_name.funciton_name()
```

This will work.let me know if you face any issue.

Tested Source Code :

```
#Test.py
def hello():
    print('Hello!')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Output Snippet: [image: Module Output]